# Save my current lat long as address on google maps from my android app

Tags: android, android-studio, google-maps-api-3, android-location

I have obtained my current latitude and longitude using `locationManager`. I want to save an address to that particular coordinates on google map if no other address exists. Could someone help me with that?

Comment: What do you mean save an address, so you need to create a place on google maps? Please clarify.

Comment: i need to add a place like if i am standing on a store so i need to retrieve the latitude and longitude of that store(which i have already done) and need then save a name to it. like we do it in google maps app. @RonnyShibley

Comment: Hi @Rishabh, question was a bit of confusing, specify one thing, do you want the address of particular lat,lng coordinates like(street name, state,country), please clarify your question?

Comment: Take it like this if i have a store and i find that my store is not mentioned on google maps so instead of saving  my store name from maps app i want to store it from my own app. How would i do that? @RamKoti